# Trouble with python relative imports

Tags: python

I have a project that is structured as below:

```
folderA
  |
  -> classA.py
  -> classB.py
  -> __init__.py
  -> folderB
      |
      -> test.py
```

I need to import `classA` in `test.py` and it doesn't work. 
I've tried the following

1. `from folderA import classA`. This throws an error saying `No module named folderA`
2. `from ...folderA import classA`. This results in `attempted relative import with no known parent package`

Can anyone help me in solving this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: What is your PYTHONPATH? Can you post the result of `import sys; print(sys.path)`?

Comment: [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14132789/10315163). Hope this help.

Comment: How are you running your test.py script? (ie `python test.py` from inside folderB? `python  -m folderA.folderB.test`?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the correct python syntax is `from ...folderA.classA import Function`. I've also often found it easier to just append the specific folder I need to use to `sys.path` like this: `sys.path.append(folderA)` . Note that you probably need the full path to FolderA for this to work.

Comment: They're running in `test.py`, which is inside `folderB`, so they should instead be appending `folderA` to the path.

Comment: Edited to fix this